# OOB configuration management software for Nginx and PHP-FPM?

Tags: server, php, nginx, automation, configuration-management

I have a question regarding configuration management (automation) of Nginx and PHP-FPM:

**1)** To allow full gzip functionality on Nginx I execute:

```
sed -i "s/# gzip_/gzip_/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**2)** To increase uploads size, and upload security I change my PHP-FPM `php.ini` this way:

```
sed -i "s/post_max_size = .M/post_max_size = 250M/ ; s/upload_max_filesize = .M/upload_max_filesize = 250M/" /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
sed -i "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/" /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
```

---

I'd prefer to avoid executing these commands as there might be better, more "standard" ways to automatically make these changes, and the files could be changed any time so the command will break. I assume there are some "immediate" conf sets one could install with `apt-get install` or something like that, that already include the above changes.

Is there some configuration automation solution that covers these confs Out Of Box?

After reading some Ansible documentation I don't think installing and configuring Ansible just for automating these operations is justified (even if I had 2-3 more similar operations, I still doubt it would be justified).

Is there some OOB configuration management software for Nginx and PHP-FPM to automate these operations (and maybe similar others) common and supported in the Ubuntu community?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem (Nginx), use the `conf.d/` directory to create an overrides file for Nginx (`nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/overrides.conf`). In this, for example, disable all server tokens:

```
# Disable server version
server_tokens off;
```

---

For the second problem (PHP), use the `mods-available/` directory to create an `zzz_overrides.ini` file and enable the module (`/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/zzz_overrides.ini`). `zzz_` is to make sure it's loaded as the last ini:

```
expose_php = Off
```